# How to keep adding a job to a background queue after it executes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I'm building a Rails 5.1 app using `delayed_job` as my background processor and using the Rails `ActiveJob` API.

I have a job that syncs records between 2 applications that I need to run each hour.  When the job is finished, it should re-add (enqueue) itself to the queue again so it can run the next hour.

However, if the job fails, it attempts the job again up to 5 times (delayed_job default is 25 attempts) before failing.

**Questions:**

Is this the best approach to keeping a job running (ie, re-adding to the queue after it performs)?  If not, what is a better approach?

Does `after_perform` take into account exceptions or failures? If it fails 5 times, will it re-add itself 5 times to the queue, or just once?

How do I ensure that this job will always be added to the queue, even if it fails?  I'm ok with it failing continually, as long as it keeps adding itself to the queue.

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
end

class SyncJob < ApplicationJob
  after_perform :add_self_to_queue

  def perform
    # do stuff...
  end

  private

  def add_self_to_queue
    self.class.set(wait_until: next_run_at_time).perform_later
  end

  def next_run_at_time
    1.hour.from_now.beginning_of_hour
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd use `whenever` and do something like: `every 1.hour { runner "SyncJob.perform_later" }`

Comment: https://github.com/javan/whenever